# Upload vhd to Azure using Azure CLI

Tags: bash, azure, azure-storage, azure-cli2

I am trying to upload a VHD to Azure using the Azure CLI.
I am using Bash for Ubuntu for Windows.
I am following these instruction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/upload-vhd

Its at this stage here i get stuck and i am not sure what to do.

az storage blob upload --account-name mystorageaccount \
    --account-key key1 --container-name mydisks --type page \
    --file /path/to/disk/mydisk.vhd --name myDisk.vhd

I get the following error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/_Downloads/myvhd.vhd'

The resource groups, storage disks created fine.
How do i proceed?

Machine is windows 10 pro, latest SPs, node.js, bash for ubuntu for windows, azure cli installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you need node.js? az uses python. old azure cli uses node.js, but you are clearly using new one (`az` - new vs `azure` -old).

also, you should probably use a proper path like `/mnt/c/_Downloads/myvhd.vhd`. Since you are using WSL you should give it a path that makes sense in WSL.

To access data on your hard drive, you should use the `/mnt/` folder, it has all the drives mounted over there

Comment: Sorry, was doing something else with node and had that in my head. Yes installed python. I have done what you suggested and copied the VHD to the WSL located at C:\Users\**user**\AppData\Local\lxss\mnt\c and then used that path /mnt/c/myvhd.vhd but i get the same error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/c/myvhd.vhd'

Comment: so if your vhd is in `C:\Users**user**\AppData\Local\lxss\mnt\c` your wsl path would be something like `mnt/C/Users**user**/AppData/Local/lxss/mnt/c` I've never actually tried putting the file inside WSL file system, I would imagine that is not supported

Comment: Thanks, progress made but now i get '[Errno 13] Permission denied:' i am running bash as administrator

Comment: chmod the file? `su chmod 777 path_to_file`, also try running az as administrator in wsl

Comment: Thanks for the help, you were right with your first answer. I just realized i had a typo in my path. when i changed it to '/mnt/c/_Downloads/myvhd.vhd'. The full command to make this work was:

az storage blob upload --account-name myStorageAccount \
    --account-key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --container-name myDisks --type page \
    --file /mnt/c/_Downloads/myvhd.vhd --name myvhd.vhd